# Classifying spaces of topological categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I try to understand and compare the following facts about maps into classifying spaces of topological categories. Consider first the following definition cited from Moerdijk's *Classifying Spaces and Classifying Topoi*.

A *linear order* over a topological space $X$ is a (set-valued) sheaf $L$ on $X$ (also known as etale topological space) together with a subsheaf $\mathcal{O} \subseteq L\ \times_X\ L$, such that for each point $x \in X$ the stalk $L_x$ is non-empty and linearly ordered by the relation 
$$
y \leq z \quad iff \quad (y,z) \in \mathcal{O}_x
$$
This defines a simplicial topological space $N_{\bullet}$ with
$$
N_m(L) = \{(y_0, \dots, y_n) |\ y_0 \leq \dots \leq y_n\ in\ L \}
$$
Now let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category internal to topological spaces. A morphism of linear orders is a map of sheaves which restricts to an order-preserving map on the stalks.

An *augmentation* of $L$ is a map of simplicial spaces $N_{\bullet}(L) \to Nerve_{\bullet}(\mathcal{C})$. A morphism of augmented linear orders is a morphism of linear orders that respects the augmentations. The category of augmented linear orders will be denoted by $Lin(X,\mathcal{C})$. Two elements of this category will be called *concordant* if there is an augmented linear order over $X \times [0,1]$, such that it restricts to the given ones over the endpoints. Denote by $Lin_c(X,\mathcal{C})$ the concordance classes.

The last theorem in Moerdijk's book says:

> > If $\mathcal{C}$ is a locally contractible topological category and $X$ is a CW-complex, then there is a bijection
> >     $$ [X, B\mathcal{C}] \cong Lin_c(X,\mathcal{C}) .$$

There is another result about maps of this kind, which is quite similar and can be found in a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612549) by Baas, Bökstedt and Kro and says

> > Assume that $X$ is a CW-complex and $Z_{\bullet}$ is a good simplicial space, then geometric realization induces a bijection $$Con_{Z_{\bullet}}(X) \cong [X, |Z_{\bullet}|] $$

where the elements of $Con_{Z_{\bullet}}(X)$ are given by maps of simplicial spaces of the form $\mathcal{U}_{\bullet} \to Z_{\bullet}$, where $\mathcal{U}_{\bullet}$ denotes the ordered Cech-complex as a simplicial space build from an ordered open cover of $X$. Taking $Z_{\bullet}$ to be the nerve of $\mathcal{C}$ we get a bijection
$$
Lin_c(X, \mathcal{C}) \cong Con_{Nerve(\mathcal{C})_{\bullet}}(X)
$$
for nice enough topological categories $\mathcal{C}$.

After this lengthy explanation here is my question:

> > Since you can cook up a linear order from an ordered covering of $X$ there is a map $$Con_{Nerve(\mathcal{C})_{\bullet}}(X) \to Lin_c(X, \mathcal{C})$$ which should fit into the setup described above.
> >     So somehow it seems to be the case that every linear order is concordant to one coming from an ordered covering. Is this true? Can this be proven directly?
> >
> > EDIT: Can I prove directly that the above map is a bijection, i.e. does every *augmented*  linear order come from one induced by an open covering?

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_0$ and $L_1$ be two linear orders over $X$ (I think of these as being the etale space). Let $L'_0 = L_0 \times [0,1)$, which is an etale space over $X \times [0,1]$; let $L'_1 = L_1 \times (0,1]$ which is another etale spacer over $X \times [0,1]$.

Define $L = L'_0 \coprod L'_1$, with the order relation that everything in $L'_1$ is larger than everything in $L'_0$ (in each fibre). This is a linear order over $X \times [0,1]$, so a concordance from $L_0$ to $L_1$. This shows that any two linear orders are concordant. In particular, the result you wanted follows immediately.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to solve the case, where $\mathcal{C}$ is the category with one object and one morphism (i.e. where there is no augmentation). Or is this also the answer to the general case? I clarified the question a little. 

Comment: No, it doesn't. I had misunderstood your question.